# Exact value in search in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I have some code which is responsible for search. The main problem that it's required to have exact results. For example, users of my website find orders by phome number.
There are three orders with numbers 8900500, 8900600, 8900700. If I put "8900", the website will show all orders. But it would be right to show nothing. Only in case of put "8900600" the website must show the order with "8900600" and so one. How can I fix it?
Now, there is the code:

```
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(search))
                query = query.Where(x => EF.Functions.Like(x.Telephone, $"%{search}%"));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use like, which also finds substrings. If you want to find exact results only, use the `==` operator:

```
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(search))
    query = query.Where(x => x.Telephone == search);
```